# Is this possible to get 3rd level sub menus/items using WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

My WordPress website menu structure is bellow:

```
menu1                     menu2      menu3      menu4
   sub menu 1
       Under sub menu 1 
       Under sub menu 1  
   sub menu 2
       Under sub menu 2 
       Under sub menu 2 
   sub menu 3 
       Under sub menu 3 
       Under sub menu 3
```

now is it possible to get **under sub menu 1 and 2** from the **sub menu 1** ? I can get the **sub menu 1** **ID** then how can I get all items under this **sub menu 1**?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the debug code below to find the specifics of your menus:

```
$menus = get_registered_nav_menus();
//Navigation Menus
print_r($menus);
foreach($menus as $menuKey => $menuValue){
    $locations = get_nav_menu_locations();
    $menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object( $locations[ $menuKey ] );
    $menuitems = wp_get_nav_menu_items( $menu->term_id, array( 'order' => 'DESC' ) );
    //Sub Menus
    print_r($menuitems);
}
exit();
```